# Keeping array with React Native Redux and adding or deleting items with combine reducers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I've been writing React for a while. In my app, there is a form with http request, and if the response is successful, the are parameters that I need to keep. I also give conditions and organize the flattest according to these parameters. I'm trying to keep these parameters with redux array. However, I add these parameters in redux array, but ı can't delete.And where do I call the delete function? I left codes below. Please help me.

```
//actions.js 
export const ADD_LIST='ADD_LIST'; // add to redux list
export const DELETE_LIST='DELETE_LIST'; //delete redux list 

export const add_List = (list) => {
  return { type: ADD_LIST, payload: list };
};

export const delete_List = (item) => {
  return { type: DELETE_LIST, payload:item};
};

//rootReducer.js
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import {userReducer} from "./userReducer";
import {listReducer} from "./listReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  userState:userReducer,
  ListState:listReducer,
})

//listReducer.js
import {ADD_LIST} from "./actions";
import {DELETE_LIST} from "./actions";


const INITIAL_STATE={
    list:[]
}

export function listReducer(state=INITIAL_STATE,action){
    switch (action.type){
        case 'ADD_LIST':
            return{...state,
                list:[...state.list,action.payload]
            };
        case 'DELETE_LIST':
            return{
                list:[
                    ...state.list.filter(item=>item!==action.payload) //I don't know if it is true?
                ]
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

//Http Request
if (xmlhttp.responseText.includes("S0000")) {
 Alert.alert("Success", "Success. ", [
                         {text: 'OK', onPress: () => exitAction()},
 
                     ],
                     {cancelable: true}
                 )
 setData(oldArray => [...oldArray, {id: id, date: date}]) //if the result is successful, i set user's id and date to a state that has name data
 dispatch(ADD_LIST(data));
 }
 
  <FlatList
  renderItem={({item,index})=> {
  let count=0;
  data?.map((userData)=>{
           if(userData.id===item.id&&userData.date===moment().format('DD-MM-   YYYY')).{ //I want if this condition not met, delete the item redux array.
            count+=1;
           }
         })
         return(
         <View style={[styles.flatlistInnerContainer,count!==0&&{backgroundColor:'rgba(108,210,147,0.62)'}]}></View>
         )        
 })
 />
 
 //I also want visible filter for the redux array. I dont work with redux toolkit or slice. Please Help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

The data looks like it has an `id` property that you should use to uniquely identify an array element object that you want to remove from the array.

Example object: `{ id, date }`

Deleting an item `dispatch(delete_List(item));` where `item` is the entire object.

Reducer logic:

```
case 'DELETE_LIST':
  return {
    ...state, // <-- shallow copy state
    list: state.list.filter( // <-- filter creates new array reference
      item => item.id !== action.payload.id
    ),
  }
```

Comment: K, but how do I fix the initial state?

Comment: @ttars What's wrong with the initial state `{ list: [] }`?

Comment: isnt it necessary to {id , date} when adding?

Comment: @ttars Sorry, what is your question specifically about? It seemed to me your question was about deleting from the array. Is that not the case? Does the data you are populating the `list` state with not match `{ id, date }`?

Comment: sorry, I'm all confused, but I understand you, thanks for your comments.

Comment: @ttars FWIW I looked over what I *think* is your UI code fetching some data and updating some local `data` state *and then* takes the data and dispatches the `add_List` action. I think `data` won't have updated just yet. Can you edit your post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: I can send the full code if I can contact you

Comment: @ttars Could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code? If you've hosted it in github you can directly import.

Comment: sorry I don't know use code sandbox

Comment: Have a public repo you don't mind linking out?

Comment: Nope, i have company repo, but thanks for your attention

Comment: @ttars I see. Then a running codesandbox may be the next best thing. It's an online IDE that is effectively a vscode clone. IMO it's very easy to use and novice-friendly.

Comment: K, i will share ASAP, thanks for your attention!